# Doctrine and Symfony2 ManyToMany: Association refers to inverse side that doesn't exist error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Im trying to establish a many to many relationship between two Entities
All I need is the exact same code that is documented here:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

here is the example code in case you don't want to open the link

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
     * @JoinTable(name="users_groups")
     **/
    private $groups;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->groups = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}

/** @Entity **/
class Group
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="groups")
     **/
    private $users;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Here is my code:

```
//My User entity
namespace Gabriel\UserBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class User extends BaseUser
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Gabriel\UploadBundle\Entity\Image", mappedBy="imageowner")
     */
    protected $ownedimage;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ownedimage = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    //...
}


//My Image entity

namespace Gabriel\UploadBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Gabriel\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="ownedimage")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="imageowner_ownedimage")
     */
    protected $imageowner;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->imageowner = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

It triggers this error:

> The association Gabriel\UploadBundle\Entity\Image#imageowner refers to
>   the inverse side field Gabriel\UserBundle\Entity\User#ownedimage which
>   does not exist.

I have been searching for hours I would appreciate if someone had an idea

Comment: I guess you tried to clear the cache? Are your bundles all defined in AppKernel.php? In config.yml?

Comment: yes yes and yes, also you can't clear the cache because the console would trigger the error.

Comment: So you manually removed the `dev` folder inside `app/cache` ?

Comment: doesn't the cache rebuild automatically when the app_dev.php is triggered?

Comment: also tried that now, same thing, but I found another way to solve the problem so doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Why a ManyToMany relationship. For me it's a OneToMany relationship.